# Is there a way to keep Scene props updated? - react-native-router-flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

When using RNRF we pass props through `Actions.fooScene({type: ActionConst.Type, data: this.some.data})`, by doing this we are setting our next scene (fooScene) props as a static value.

If I connect redux with the next scene, I will be able to know that the store has changed (as it will trigger `componentWillReceiveProps()`), but in my situation I am fetching data from Firebase at very top level and passing the data through ListView - there is no way for me to check the specific state property of store in `fooScene`. All I can do is pass the data from `Actions.fooScene()`.

Is there a way where we can keep our next scene props updated?

Comment: Why not just keep the data in the store and connect the `fooScene` component to it?

Comment: @Igorsvee Thank your for replying, I did exactly as you stated. But I needed to know if there was some auto-passing of props function available in docs or some package which I didnt knew about.